# Error Code 1062 (and many more questions to come)

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and taking an online community college course for work.  I keep getting the message ***Error Code 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key Primary***  My understanding would be that the Primary Key cannot be duplicated but it isn't so I am not sure what the issue is.  I have tried changing the Primary keys but it just keeps coming back with the same message but a different primary key number.

Here is the script (part of it - there are alot more entries but they are all formatted the same):

```
Insert into pres_term values ( 1, '1789-07-01', '1797-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek re-election');
Insert into pres_term values ( 2, '1797-03-04', '1801-03-04', 1, 'Lost reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 3, '1801-03-04', '1809-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 4, '1809-03-04', '1817-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 5, '1817-03-04', '1825-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 6, '1825-03-04', '1829-03-04', 1, 'Lost reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 7, '1829-03-04', '1837-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 8, '1837-03-04', '1841-03-04', 2, 'Did not seek reelection');
Insert into pres_term values ( 9, '1841-03-04', '1841-04-04', 1, 'Died in office');
```

Comment: Hi there welcome to StackOverflow, what does the `pres_term` tables look like? It is difficult to provide help if there isn't [sufficient or complete information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Is the table empty before you run these commands?

Comment: do you have any triggers in play?

Comment: The table script is below:                                                                                            CREATE TABLE pres_term
(
  pres_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  term_start_date DATETIME(6),
  term_end_date DATETIME(6),
  number_of_elections_won INT(10),
  reason_for_leaving_office CHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (pres_id)
  ) ;                                                                                                                           The table is empty.  No triggers.